# Перевод на другую страницу JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте

Столкнулся с проблемой. Раньше я использовал хостинг от Яндекса, так как вполне хватало HTML. Однако потребности выросли и пришлось переезжать на хостинг, где поддерживается PHP.  На старую страницу я поместил скрипт, чтобы старые пользователи не терялись:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            navigate("http://www.tuda.ru/index.php");
        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

был очень доволен, когда заметил результат в Opera. Тут же разочаровался, когда узнал что на Mozila firefox скрипт не работает и не перебрасывает никуда...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение данной проблемы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Три варианта (js и html):

```
location.replace('[URL]');  
location.href = '[URL]';  
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=[URL]">
```

[URL] - нужный адрес.

Comment: Спасибо отличный ответ!

Comment: Если не трудно - поясните пожалуйста - чем отличается 
    location.replace('[URL]');  
от
    location.href = '[URL]';

Comment: location.replace не оставляет адрес страницы в истории посещений, то есть, нельзя будет вернуться по кнопке "Назад". location.href работает как клик по ссылке.

Comment: Спасибо) Плюсую!)

Comment: так же есть вариант с однопиксельным флеш-роликом, который после того как загрузится - перекинет на требуемую страницу