# Редирект через время

Tags: html, php, javascript

Как сделать редирект с сайта example.com на сайт example.ru, так чтобы пользователь пошел на сайт example.com, пробыл там 10 секунд, а потом его сослало на example.ru.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javascript

`setTimeout(function(){
    location.href = 'example.com';
}, 10000);`

Answer (score 2):

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16895/перевод-на-другую-страницу-javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16895/)

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерчик - [PHP redirect (перенаправление)](http://ru-info.net/index.php?page=post&id=2)

Answer (score 1):

Выставив location.href через некоторое время по таймауту:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

    function doRedirect() {
        atTime = "1000";
        toUrl = "http://example.com";

        setTimeout("location.href = toUrl;", atTime);
    }

</script>

<body onload="doRedirect();">
</body>
```